# How to listen to media session events of another app

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-bluetooth, android-mediasession

I have created an app that can listen to headphones action using media sessions and perform custom actions but when another music player platform like spotify or default music player is used media session is change and I can’t listen to actions so what do i do if i want to listen to those action?

I don’t know how to do it.Do any body have some idea also you can share your Experience anything related to this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.